# Equivalent different-order difference equations--implications, if any?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, difference-equations

I have a sequence of rational values. If I apply the `FindSequenceFunction` command to the first 48 (but no fewer) I get the result

```
    DifferenceRoot[
  Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {12 \[FormalN] (1 + \[FormalN]) \
(2 + 3 \[FormalN]) (4 + 3 \[FormalN]) (3 + 4 \[FormalN]) (5 + 
         4 \[FormalN]) (98112700402088693217189553 + 
         99806215594122374254898540 \[FormalN] + 
         25000489169807709332127307 \[FormalN]^2) \[FormalY][\
\[FormalN]] + (94893095119183156525820612256000 + 
         358110436897721213666569966103040 \[FormalN] + 
         561625527445127175394367926986832 \[FormalN]^2 + 
         462950330315338075191044081483620 \[FormalN]^3 + 
         195100972584890679758154599712272 \[FormalN]^4 + 
         17948682395172776066429346525325 \[FormalN]^5 - 
         20150580892912879148765994774007 \[FormalN]^6 - 
         8662956699444420887214929059505 \[FormalN]^7 - 
         1124945272794176991691298633897 \[FormalN]^8) \[FormalY][
        1 + \[FormalN]] + (-2907795557580683867826931618416000 - 
         10790849885266466683295769064431360 \[FormalN] - 
         16956796738315192834473445635213912 \[FormalN]^2 - 
         14482227568454070093531814822914860 \[FormalN]^3 - 
         6994466688290399284513246949800032 \[FormalN]^4 - 
         1630058554767192359067959717328110 \[FormalN]^5 + 
         33613363833210621486221336908902 \[FormalN]^6 + 
         103726360843481140486461275282530 \[FormalN]^7 + 
         16288666376972942775486666256602 \[FormalN]^8) \[FormalY][
        2 + \[FormalN]] + (52107490669688916706189556995507200 + 
         189582744653170367324554659119770560 \[FormalN] + 
         297962302363997605784953431628125664 \[FormalN]^2 + 
         264411465293315120983899130374356220 \[FormalN]^3 + 
         145015628335207762959241152861429516 \[FormalN]^4 + 
         50373462234979665565230370116005925 \[FormalN]^5 + 
         10830713158034397689533857662172021 \[FormalN]^6 + 
         1318712561786836297214662685473695 \[FormalN]^7 + 
         69655437589908175472190470323199 \[FormalN]^8) \[FormalY][
        3 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == 1/14, \[FormalY][2] == 
     1/429, \[FormalY][3] == 0}]][n]
```

while if I apply the command to the first (as one instance, say) 52 of the sequence I get the different-order result

```
    DifferenceRoot[
  Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {12 \[FormalN] (1 + \[FormalN]) \
(2 + 3 \[FormalN]) (4 + 3 \[FormalN]) (3 + 4 \[FormalN]) (5 + 
         4 \[FormalN]) (125010 + 365175 \[FormalN] + 
         424940 \[FormalN]^2 + 246134 \[FormalN]^3 + 
         70930 \[FormalN]^4 + 
         8131 \[FormalN]^5) \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (-762048000 - 
         10346918400 \[FormalN] - 58204697760 \[FormalN]^2 - 
         183731473896 \[FormalN]^3 - 366725069956 \[FormalN]^4 - 
         490281935526 \[FormalN]^5 - 450751812715 \[FormalN]^6 - 
         286289388101 \[FormalN]^7 - 123546989494 \[FormalN]^8 - 
         34600663964 \[FormalN]^9 - 5673316155 \[FormalN]^10 - 
         413404433 \[FormalN]^11) \[FormalY][
        1 + \[FormalN]] + (23351328000 + 258871334400 \[FormalN] + 
         1270608428880 \[FormalN]^2 + 3646167946344 \[FormalN]^3 + 
         6800332367976 \[FormalN]^4 + 8661395949038 \[FormalN]^5 + 
         7694486245215 \[FormalN]^6 + 4772668983033 \[FormalN]^7 + 
         2027879879634 \[FormalN]^8 + 562751402892 \[FormalN]^9 + 
         91895045655 \[FormalN]^10 + 
         6696228133 \[FormalN]^11) \[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 
     0, \[FormalY][1] == 1/14, \[FormalY][2] == 1/429}]][n]
```

It certainly appears that these two rather differing-appearing results are equivalent. How much insight can we gain from this equivalence? I tried applying `RSolve` to each result without any success at all. Can this equivalence be utilized in such a respect?

Bill S asked for the first 52 numbers of the sequence. Here they are:

```
{1/14, 1/429, 0, -(31/6653325), -(11/39079530), -(1/
  133134708), 1/7983491628, 239/10247133419523, 57/48680900474360, \
2903/124824596648764012, -(115/113038366701546741), -(5683/
  51064938998398029068), -(5/1058235752353477852), -(10987/
  189207192625432776867960), 217/34346888525759172651080, \
6006533/11751858254158270025487932385, \
75454/4129142821171325429499798543, \
2488/44724045029521946128276717635, -(67979/
  1949405592484607512729786754750), -(1278583/
  563886542243307051112607531706900), -(43/
  644120741172093459762934324450), \
35507/55843499825037487695502268548565300, \
26179/146085125528571118397897359986633150, \
107995819/11107198393276249496377378054920552928500, \
173273/773130782589769152255414257374217524560, -(2530040963/
  385579195426574400254370684707378274352106040), -(341661/
  390506882065707259862538728104411525357030), -(47508605/
  1180995428687920393087606343121393293355348584), -(236743223/
  365666548587374605514638686911078517746260719000), \
661103081109/14882955886130596094092636233819654161612507915753200, \
1635932929/399077436585841300109074826671732426720049873987664, \
162457739/1016537306935386214686768174455506165585626418295919, \
405598972/320724199611806418167854232367392991310116735229662969, -(
  355480075553152/
  1382226737640320426884705673240881910513010261725063720513715), -(
  25942171159264/
  1400348339083149533065036216341833673853062424536582760802289), -(
  4797093275677464/
  7943420105352744611500712278318253486385465194041442673825449047), \
2015713573747/\
1269596932181486065759798744076779236195629792356964536087568856, \
313742409433/\
229875299736671954051025219604115431048075058191077402716006256, \
132491878573/\
1637515963691963105149922964910088245418153492758015009750171952, \
23425526967173291/\
1099336721818312740359158026694968896793035515711323423457595657714982\
0, -(106581466987082639/
  27894126208338284913814651406187607828700460319744954957085215299353\
82960), -(22982499080375419/
  33655841198221084950394861090089619806856749629305036931030975920685\
68968), -(405382627801/
  11876137000313260921466125871956614060088582844055077556654968650598\
19), -(1904455526895899/
  28240167957767510069333881614843964888411766850629761010723519768156\
4227100), \
119553913643/\
3987354497266615396977360299862031205090379903880494448980358686527864\
60, 198890483930071/\
6090574909742474267654290179642756698963717939497723633679663677079059\
872810, 646781379610049/\
4664195351140737284522148684219177289500195495159386503573201063051645\
36000860, \
118582835645159/\
6939596835191067385085903002445755119881372271743978796133157788581468\
756969540, -(1887460465799/
    101781618736814422136498374205407212768683183695868590697609203787\
7864584789400), -(2276048545701655783/
    151413932748764960572111418638135242237721612874885452435303123575\
29140693277874960468), -(218135990618788675/
    404820010675809996544296819516695778521096492702355619321323627779\
28805675607575648764), -(154614017346765724505/
    896039865080825863727938144925339334896408385095907830226118029034\
3296593965357296971666088)}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to list the 52 numbers (rather than the output of the DifferenceRoot functions)?

Comment: When I apply FindSequenceFunction, I don't get any answer (for either 48 or all 52 elements)

Comment: Bill S: I just tried the FindSequenceFunction command with the posted array, and it did work. Are you using the command correctly? Also, it  is quite easy to generate the numbers themselves with the DifferenceRoot function. Just define a function, as say f[n_]:=DifferenceRoot...., and generate f[1], f[2],...,f[52].

Comment: Try copying what you pasted above for the numbers -- first I had to edit out all the backslashes. I set the list to variable `seq`. Then `FindSequenceFunction[seq] didn't return an answer. So something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater  I believe that no additional insight can be obtained from having two different expressions.  Consider as an analogy a second-order ODE.  Differentiate it once to obtain a third-order ODE and combine it with an additional boundary condition satisfying the second-order ODE.  You now have two ODEs with the same solution.  But, do you have any new information.  No!

Comment: Your question about the implications seems like a mathematics question, not a question about how to use *Mathematica*.  In *Mathematica*, it means that given that `A == B` is true, then such things as `Assuming[A == B, code]` ought to be safe.

Comment: Thanks, for all the comments! To bill s, I did, in fact, succeed once again by copying (without having to edit out backslashes). More generally, I was not very optimistic to begin with, but it seemed a question at least worth asking/clarifying--which bbgodfrey seems to have done. I also realized it was to a large extent simply a mathematics question, but the availability of the Mathematica coding seemed to make it possibly more easily addressable in that framework. I'll have to "check out" the use of the Assuming command, with which I was not familiar,  that MIchael E2 brought to attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim in my comment above that the third order recurrence relation represented by the first `DifferenceRoot` in the question is derivable symbolically from the recurrence relation represented by the second `DifferenceRoot` can be proved as follows.  Designate the two `DifferenceRoot` rusults as `d1` and `d2`.  Them, the corresponding recurrence relations are

```
r1 = (First[Head[d1]][y, n])[[1, 1]];
r2 = (First[Head[d2]][y, n])[[1, 1]];
```

and `r2` shifted applied to `n + 1` is

```
r2p = Simplify[r2 /. n -> n + 1];
```

The question is whether `r1` is a linear combination of `r2` and `r2p`.

```
c = CoefficientArrays[c1 r1 - c2 r2 - c2p r2p, 
    Table[y[n + i], {i, 0, 3}]] // Last // Normal // Simplify;
```

isolates the coefficients of the four values of `y` occurring in `c1 r1 - c2 r2 - c2p r2p`.  Finally, solve for `c2` and `c2p`

```
s = Flatten@Solve[{c[[1]] == 0, c[[4]] == 0}, {c2, c2p}];
```

and substitute the result into the remaining equations,

```
Simplify[c[[2 ;; 3]] /. s]
(* {0, 0} *)
```

completing the proof.  (`s`, a bit long to be reproduced here, gives `{c2, c2p}` in terms of `c1`.)

Although unlikely, it is conceivable that `r1` and `r2` both could be constructed from some first-order recurrence relation.  To attempt to do so, suppose that the recurrence relation is `y[n + 1] hp[n] + y[n] h[n] == 0`, and set

```
hp[n] = Simplify[Coefficient[r2, y[n + 2]] /. n -> n - 1]
h[n] = Simplify[Coefficient[r2, y[n]]]

Simplify[r2 - (y[n + 1] hp[n] + y[n] h[n]) - ((y[n + 1] hp[n] + y[n] h[n]) /. n -> n + 1)]
```

does not vanish identically, however, so the corresponding first-order relation does not exist.

Comment: Terrific, bbgodfrey! I will study your analysis.

Comment: Here's an interesting, somewhat related and rather puzzling phenomenon. For a sequence of length 48, FindSequenceFunction returns the indicated third-order recurrence relation. For sequences of length 49,...63 the indicated more concise result is presented. But for sequences of length 64 or (it seems indefinitely) greater, the FindSequenceFunction command fails to yield a formula.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater  I agree that this is strange but have no explanation.  By the way, I noticed that you have asked 12 questions but accepted no answers.  Perhaps, this is because you have not read the `Tour` under `Help`.  I urge you to do so.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks bbgodfrey for pointing out the "Tour". I accepted the highly-responsive, very nicely composed answer. Might this quirk in the use of the FindSequenceFunction command possibly merit a question of its own?

Comment: @PaulB.Slater  I doubt that you will receive a useful answer, because this strange behavior probably is an idiosyncrasy of the internal workings of `FindSequenceFunction`.  You could report it to Wolfram, Inc as a bug and see what response you get.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to check if two different `DifferenceRoot[]` expressions are supposed to be the same is to use `DifferenceRootReduce[]`, like so:

```
d1 = (* third-order expression *);
d2 = (* second-order expression *);

DifferenceRootReduce[d1 - d2]
   0
```